# Preventing text-wrapping inside JavaDoc

Tags: javadoc, word-wrap

Let's say I have the following section inside a JavaDoc definition:

```
/**
 * [... blah blah ...] It will then call the <code>onFile...()</code>-methods
 * on the provided event handler to report any changes. [... blah blah ...]
 */
```

This can lead to awkward text-wrapping so that it ends up spanning lines like this, for example:

```
............................... It will then call the onFile...
()-methods on the provided event handler to report any changes.
```

Is it possible to mark certain sections in a JavaDoc definition such as to prevent a line-wrap inside the section? In the example above: is there some way to prevent the `onFile...()` inside the `<code>`-tag to wrap, but still have it appear inline with the rest of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<nobr>`-tag is not standard html, so the following is probably "bad style", but it works:

```
/**
 * [... blah blah ...] It will then call the <nobr><code>onFile...()</code>
 * </nobr>-methods on the provided event handler to report any changes.
 * [... blah blah ...]
 */
```

It will force the displayed text to instead wrap earlier:

```
............................... It will then call the
onFile...()-methods on the provided event handler to report any
changes.
```

Now, I only wish I could define my own "macro-tag", such that I can use `<nbc> ... </nbc>` instead of `<nobr><code> ... </code></nobr>`.